# How to develop a retrosynthesis plan for 2-[(E)-2-(3-bromophenyl)ethenyl]-1,3-benzoxazole?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, synthesis

I need to retro-synthetically design a valid synthesis plan (in two steps, from cheap starting materials available over at Sigma Aldrich) for a target compound, pictured below.

[image: 2-[(E)-2-(3-bromophenyl)ethenyl]-1,3-benzoxazole]

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Extempore, this should be available by the reaction of 3-bromocinnamaldehyde with 2-aminophenol. Samarium triflate as a catalyst might be a good idea.

[image: retrosynthesis of benzoxazole]

In any case, I'd start the retrosynthesis at the benzoxazole moiety.

Comment: Thank you very much! In the meantime I tried to develop another strategy as well, I've done some research and found another way to synthesize this via reaxys. If I may, I do have a follow up question regarding this: would this reaction go the same way if I were to react the benzoxazole without the halogen (F)? If not, is there a way to remove it from the target molecule? Here's a link to the ![synthesis plan](http://i.imgur.com/fZjz6ID.png). Once again, thank you very much for the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

How about a more classic Wittig reaction between [3-Bromobenzaldehyde](http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/catalog/product/aldrich/b57206?lang=en&region=US) and [2-(chloromethyl)-1,3-benzoxazole](http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/catalog/product/aldrich/cds016769?lang=en&region=US)?